# How to update page in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my page I have displaying data in table and each row having a delete button, I need to update that table after successfully  deleting that row,
I have tried `window.location.reload()` but didn't worked.

```
     </va-card>
    <br/>
      <va-card >
        <va-table :hover="hover" :size="size" v- 
         if="approveduserData.length"  >
          <table  style="width:100%;" >
            <thead >
              <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-size:19px">
                <th >Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                 <th>Delete User</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in approveduserData">
              <td style="font-weight:bold">{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
               <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                <td><va-button  color="danger"  v- 
            on:click="Deactivate(user.email,user.username)"> 
          Deactivate</va-button></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </va-table>
      </va-card>
```

// below is my deactivate function

```
             Deactivate:function(email,name){
         const rejectUser = {
          "email":email
        }
        if(confirm("Do you want to Remove "+ name +" Account??"))
        {
              axios.post('http://34.67.88.0:3000/api/userrejected',rejectUser)
              .then(function(res){
                self.outputRejected = res.data;
                if(self.outputRejected){
                  alert(  name+" Account Successfully Deleted!!")

                }
              })
              .catch(function(error){
                console.log("Error",error)
              })
             }
         }
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback of a successfull deletion on the Server you can manipulate the local copy for example:

```
          .then(function(res){
            self.outputRejected = res.data;
            if(self.outputRejected){
              this.approveduserData = this.approveduserData.filter(x => x.name !== name) <--
              alert(  name+" Account Successfully Deleted!!")

            }
```

There are more clean options of remvoing the entry from the local array but the logic should be the same.

Comment: @pavankp Well I told you the logic to solve it and `not working bro..` is really helping with troubleshooting.. whatever have fun

Comment: @pavankp But I expect the issue to be in my sample I called it `name` because you accept that as a parameter but in reality its about the `username`

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an object vue will not detect the change (on a data property), you have a few options but the simplest would be to place a key on elements you need to reload and then when updating the data property update the key on the elements as well, this will force the reload.
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

```
//template
<va-card :key="reloadKey">
...
data(){
  return {
    reloadKey:0,
    approveduserData: []
    }

.then(...update local data property, reloadKey++)
```